# jquery.printElement not responding at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I've been trying to use the jquery.printElement plugin but nothing happens when I click on the Print link, except for this error message in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opera' of undefined

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Print</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="content">Some text to print</p>
    <a href="#" id="printIt">Print</a>
<script src="../common/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../common/js/jquery.printElement.js"></script>
<script>
$('#printIt').click(function() {
    $('#content').printElement();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The printElement plugin uses jQuery.browser internally, and $.browser has been deprecated and removed in the version of jQuery you're using.

You have to use an older version of jQuery, or possibly the migrate plugin to make printElement work.

Comment: Ah. That explains a lot.

Comment: I've downloaded the Migrate plugin and it's working fine now - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

wrap code inside `document.ready`.

```
$(function()
{
    $('#printIt').click(function()
    {
        $('#content').printElement();
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not making any difference at all - it still returns the same error message and doesn't work.

Comment: @DorianFabre make sure jQuery version are compatible with plugin because i read on `printElement` website they had this line `reference path="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" />` https://raw.github.com/erikzaadi/jQueryPlugins/master/jQuery.printElement/jquery.printElement.min.js